# Load uitableview data after viewdidappear occurs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

On the change of one view to another i want to load uitableview data after the viewdidappear of the new view occurs because if i load them in viewdidload it takes too much time to update the interface and the reason is the data loading. I want the interface to be loaded first so the user will be presented with the new interface and a "Loading..." label. Then data loading will occur and lastly the uitableview will appear.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what was the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your data in the background as follows. Fill in the details with your own code to update your UI as you like and track status of the data being loaded. You can also look into other methods of executing background ops (look at the Concurrency Programming Guide) for more options and control.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)loadData
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    // load the data
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didLoadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
}

- (void)didLoadData
{
}
```